# Nonparametric test for 1 categorical IV and multiple binary DV:s?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons

I have a dataset where test subjects have answered three different questions (my IV). The answers to each question are scored on 10 different variables (presence or absence of 10 concepts in the answer to each queation). Now I want to test whether are significant differences in these 10 binary variables depending on the question.

Since this is a within-subjects design and I have binary variables I cannot use Manova.

I was thinking about Cochran's Q but since I have three different treatments (questions) and 10 variables for each treatment it doesn't work.

Do anyone have any suggestions how to proceed? Can I use multiple Cochran's Q, one test for each variable and then do some alpha-correction like Bonferroni?